# Perfectly working Heroku app crashed and unable to restart

Tags: heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, spree, heroku-postgres

My Rails app that uses Spree and is hosted on Heroku was working fine until last night but I woke up this morning to find that the app had crashed and I have no clue why. I have not made any changes recently. I tried heroku restart without success. It looks like something is up with Heroku (the log is asking me a question about whether the amazon host is running??) How do I let them know to resolve this for me?

```
2013-06-04T06:47:59.795210+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1076:in `initialize': could not connect to server: Connection refused (PGError)
2013-06-04T06:47:59.795659+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/spree-58e0391d3496/core/config/initializers/spree.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
2013-06-04T06:47:59.795210+00:00 app[web.1]:    Is the server running on host "ec2-54-243-188-56.compute-1.amazonaws.com" and accepting
2013-06-04T06:47:59.795210+00:00 app[web.1]:    TCP/IP connections on port 5442?
```

Comment: The error says it all. Is the server running on host "ec2-54-243-188-56.compute-1.amazonaws.com"? Please check if your server is running.

Comment: Database issue – should be fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to http://help.heroku.com and [Open a Support Ticket](https://help.heroku.com/tickets/new)

Answer (score 0):

Check logs from terminal

```
heroku logs --app <heroku app name>
```

check the crash stacktrace and then restart all dynos from dashboard

[image]